# How To Buy Digix gold tokens

Tags: digix

I cannot figure out how to buy Digix gold tokens using Ethereum.  I download Ethereum's wallet on my computer and it disappeared.  Something about "unpacking." I use Coinbase, but they limit purchases to less than $2500 without uploading your drivers license.  That completely eliminates all privacy and anonymity.

How do I buy Digix gold tokens?

Thx

Comment: Hi there, Michael. Is your question: "How do I buy Digix (with or without ETH)?" or more "How do I convert ETH to another currency?"

Comment: How do I buy Digix with ETH?

Comment: I just got a message from Digix saying they are revising their platform and will let me know when I can buy Digix DAO (or DGX).  Seems like an excellent idea - gold backed cryptocurrency.  I don't know how reputable they are though . . .